# JPA OneToMany insert not setting the id's correctly

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have two entities, let's say

Person.java:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personData", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<SkillsData> skillsData;
        // ...
    }
```

SkillsData.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SkillsData")
public class SkillsData implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    private long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSONID")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = REMOVE)
    private Person personData;
    // ...
}
```

When I create a person, add a list of type SkillsData to it's skillsData field and persist it everything works with no exceptions thrown, but when I browse the database directly in the SkillsData table the field PERSONID is not populated and because of that the skills added can't be referenced to the right person.
I'm trying to fix this problem for quite some time and I'll be thankful for any help.

Comment: It would help if you mentioned the DBMS you are using and what the table create statement looks like.

Comment: It may be a typo, or maybe I am just very rusty on Entities, but your `@JoinColumn` is "PERSONID", but it looks like your column name is just "id" on a "person" table

Comment: @CodeChimp: You misunderstand JoinColumn, it represents a (foreign key) column in SkillsData named PERSONID.

Comment: You should post part of your code which actually saves the entities.

Comment: @Gimby, you are correct.  Had to think back to how this worked.  As you stated above, would have helped to see some DDL or something, then I could have gotten the pieces right in my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be in the fact that you're not setting `SkillsData.personData` before persisting leaving it null.

You **must** set it cause adding SkillsData to the `Person.skillsData` list is not enough since you declared this side of relationship as **inverse**(mappedBy attribute).

Therefore it is the `SkillsData.personData` non-inverse side who is responsible for establishing this relationship.